# strpos() using $haystack from an array element

Tags: php

Im trying to get the location of a substring from a string that has been extracted from an array. Im trying to use this code
`$var = $posts['data']['children']['0']['data']['url']; 
$newvar = strpos($var,"&t=");`

when $var is echoed, it show this `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIHF5EoEixc&feature=youtu.be&t=3m36s`

but when $newvar is echoed, nothing is there.
How do i do this?

Comment: Use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) and look at the source code (not the rendered HTML). Could be that `&` is actually a `&amp;`. Also properly check the return value of your `strpos()`, if the string wasn't found it will return `FALSE` which echo'ed returns nothing

Comment: With `$var = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIHF5EoEixc&feature=youtu.be&t=3m36s";` and your code, I get `$newvar = 60;`. Are you sure that `$posts['data']['children']['0']['data']['url']` contains the string you are looking for? Is there code in between `$var` and `$newvar` that you're not telling us about?

Comment: variable $newvar return 60